# Overriding paranoid verification code devise security controller in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, devise, overriding

I followed these steps:

add this in Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise-security', '~> 0.16.0'
```

run this command:

```
rails generate devise_security:install
```

add paranoid_verification in the resource model file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :invitable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :validatable, :saml_authenticatable, :paranoid_verification
```

customize route:

```
  devise_for :users,
     path: '',
     path_names: {
       sign_in: 'signin',
       registration: 'signup',
       confirmation: 'verification',
     },
    controllers: {
      sessions: 'users/sessions',
      registrations: 'users/registrations',
      confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
      passwords: 'users/passwords',
      invitations: 'users/invitations',
      verification_code: 'users/paranoid_verification_code',
    },
    skip: [:unlocks, :omniauth_callbacks, :saml_authenticatable],
    defaults: { format: :json }
```

add my own controller in app/controllers/users/paranoid_verification_code_controller.rb:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::ParanoidVerificationCodeController < Devise::ParanoidVerificationCodeController
  skip_before_action :handle_paranoid_verification
  prepend_before_action :authenticate_scope!, only: [:show, :update]
```

but rake routes still show the following:

```
      user_paranoid_verification_code GET      /verification_code(.:format)                                                             devise/paranoid_verification_code#show {:format=>:json}
                                  PATCH    /verification_code(.:format)                                                             devise/paranoid_verification_code#update {:format=>:json}
                                  PUT      /verification_code(.:format)                                                             devise/paranoid_verification_code#update {:format=>:json}
```

what am i doing wrong?? the other controllers (invitable, registerable etc) works correctly though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it should be

```
paranoid_verification_code: 'users/paranoid_verification_code',
```